# Echarts redraw issue

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I have a large React echart graph with multiple series. There is an issue with redraw or something but I have no idea where to start debugging. I don;t know if it is my code or an issue with eachart.
issue is mainly happening where moving the datazoom.

[image]

```json
dataZoom: [
        {
            id: 'dataZoomX',
            type: 'inside',
            xAxisIndex: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            filterMode: 'weakFilter',
            start: 85,
            end: 100,
            //preventDefaultMouseMove: true,
            zoomOnMouseWheel: false,
            //moveOnMouseMove: true,
            moveOnMouseWheel: true, // wheel = horizontal
        },
        {
            show: true,
            xAxisIndex: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            type: 'slider',
            top: 15,
            // filterMode: "weakFilter",
            start: 85,
            end: 100,
            handleIcon:
                'path://M10.7,11.9H9.3c-4.9,0.3-8.8,4.4-8.8,9.4c0,5,3.9,9.1,8.8,9.4h1.3c4.9-0.3,8.8-4.4,8.8-9.4C19.5,16.3,15.6,12.2,10.7,11.9z M13.3,24.4H6.7V23h6.6V24.4z M13.3,19.6H6.7v-1.4h6.6V19.6z',
            handleSize: '50%',
        },
        {
            id: 'dataZoomY',
            type: 'inside',
            yAxisIndex: [0],
            filterMode: 'none',
            zoomOnMouseWheel: false,
            moveOnMouseMove: true, // move = vertical
            //moveOnMouseWheel: true
            zoomLock: true,
            start: 30,
            end: 70,
        },
        {
            show: true,
            yAxisIndex: [0],
            type: 'slider',
            top: 65,
            filterMode: 'none',
            right: 10,
            end: 100,
            handleIcon:
                'path://M10.7,11.9H9.3c-4.9,0.3-8.8,4.4-8.8,9.4c0,5,3.9,9.1,8.8,9.4h1.3c4.9-0.3,8.8-4.4,8.8-9.4C19.5,16.3,15.6,12.2,10.7,11.9z M13.3,24.4H6.7V23h6.6V24.4z M13.3,19.6H6.7v-1.4h6.6V19.6z',
            handleSize: '50%',
        },
    ],
```

Any idea where I should start investigate?

Comment: Try to disable animation (`animation: false`). There is a known issue with animation and zooming / roaming.

Comment: Thanks. It is set to `false`
I am wondering if it is an issue with how I have set up dataZoom. Added my datazoom config

Comment: I have no other immediate ideas, sry. I would start debugging by trying to get a minimal reproducable example, i.e. throw everything out that is not causing the issue. If you have an example of managable size you can add it to the question and somebody might be able to help you.